# can one use r 4.* and visual studio > 2017

Tags: r, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I just learned that I cannot use R 4.* in Visual Studio 2017. It is recommended to use Visual Studio code. I would prefer to stick with Visual Studio as I tend to also have SQL (Server) scripts etc. in my R projects and they are source controlled via TFS. I think I can use a later version of Visual Studio (my organisation pays for it). Can I use R 4.* in Visual Studio 20++? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you editing your SQL scripts in VSCode

Comment: @HongOoi thanks. sorry about my ignorance about vccode but at the moment I have solutions in VS with projects (e.g. one Python and the other R). These solutions are source controlled. Can I consume these VS solutions in vscode? Does the solution concept exists in vscode? thanks.